# How to customize error message returning from UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an application using .Net MVC and Identity. I'm creating new users like this:

```
result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

When e-mail address is already in use, i'm getting an error message. I want to customize that error message.

My Email property in RegisterModel is looking like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email adresinizi girmediniz.")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Email adresi hatalı.")]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

How can i customize that "Email xxx already in use" message?

Answer (score 2):

In the POST method, add a `ModelState` error for the property and return the view.

```
if(EmailNotAvailable)
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Your custom error message");
  return View(model);
}
```

You can also use a `[Remote]` attribute to perform this validation on the client.

```
[Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "YourControllerName", ErrorMessage = "Your custom error message")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

and implement a controller method that checks if the email is avaliable

```
public JsonResult IsEmailAvailable(string Email)
{
  if(EmailNotAvailable)
  {
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    // or to override the error message you defined in the RemoteAttribute
    return Json("Another custom message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Refer [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx) for more details on implementing `RemoteAttribute`